# Cache and use only one object in case of equality - equal objects should get referneces

Tags: java

I have a KeyObject consuming some fair amount of memory. The KeyObject also has a hashValue and an equals Method implemented.

Now I want to hold every unique KeyObject only once in my memory and just use references to this object in case of equality (equals not ==).

I thought I could use a Set but I can not get the original KeyObject. I can only replace the existing one with a new one.

Here is what I mean in pseude code:

```
Keybject a = new Keybject("a");
Keybject b = new Keybject("a");
boolean thisIsTrue = a.equals(b);
boolean thisIsFalse a == b;

Map<KeyObject, Value> largeMapA = new HashMap<>();
Map<KeyObject, Value> largeMapB = new HashMap<>();

largeMapA.put(a, "value a");
largeMapB.put(b, "value b");
```

Now I have the large KeyObject twice -> one for each largeMap, but it would be enough to have  only one KeyObject (a.equals(b)) and use a reference for the the 2nd map.

So I want something like this:

```
KeyObject b = if there is already a equal object ("a") in my "cache" then use "a"
largeMapA.put(a, "value a");
largeMapB.put(b, "value b"); // Now I have ONE large KeyObject 
                             // this is just a reference to a
```

The only only solution that comes in mind is to loop the entry largeMapA and find a equal key then replace b:

```
for (KeyObject ko : largeMapA.keySet()) {
  if (ko.equals(b)) {
    b = ko;
    break;
  }
}
```

But this seems not to be a performant solution ...

Comment: This is almost certainly a very premature optimization. Don't worry about this and make your code a lot more complicated until you've demonstrated with a profiler that this is actually a significant problem. Generally speaking, if you have objects that are both likely to be equal and very large, something's out of whack with your core data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `HashMap<KeyObject,KeyObject>` in which the key is the same as the value.

- `if (map.contains(b))` will tell you if your cache contains the key.
- `map.get(b)` will give you that key.
- if the map doesn't contain the key, you put it there - `map.put(b,b)`

Comment: @KIC My mistake. I changed my answer

Comment: The thing to worry about are memory leaks. This retains all the keys ever used in the lifetime of the application. A second huge concern is thread safety.

Comment: In fact a maybe dirty but quick solution :-) I will accept this one since  memleaks and concurrency is no issue in my case.